# создать динамическое добавление строки для ввода данных

Tags: c#, winforms, элементы-управления

Есть форма winforms. Нужно организовать динамическое добавление строки для ввода данных через эту формую Состав строки -1 поле номер строки, второе выпадающий список с заранее определенными значениями для выбора, третье - текстовое поле для ручного ввода. По завершении ввода в строку автоматом должна вставляться такая же следующая, но пустая - для дальнейшего заполнения с увеличенным номером строки (1 поле). 
Подскажите как это сделать на C#.

Comment: Дак а с чем конкретно у вас трудности возникли?

Comment: Это DataGridView.

Comment: Какой контейнер выбрать и как организовать динамическую генерацию новой пустой строки - вот где затык.

Comment: Что уже сделали и что не получилось?

Comment: По совету использую DataGridView. Набрал колонки нужных типов. Все ок, но новая пустая строка лезет после выхода из редактирования каждой ячейки, а нужно чтобы только после заполнения всех полей в строке. И как первой колонке назначить автоинкрементный счетчик? Я делаю не вставку в базу - нужно просто поле, не id